# Networking multiple Arduino Megas and updating their programs from one master

Tags: firmware

Is it possible to link multiple Arduino Megas using RS485, for example, and update the program on client Megas from one master Mega, as well as for them to communicate with each other? Whilst I found multiple examples of networks, nothing comes up for programming the boards other than through a PC

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, yes, you can do it. It's what existing bootloaders do -- they take code over the serial port, or USB, load it to flash, and then branch to it. Not to mention OTA.

So yes, you can modify the bootloader to use different pins, talk rs485, come up with code-integrity checks, specify particular bit patterns to signal "reboot" or "now load new code", and so on. If you have enough flash, you can even keep two copies, a working and a new, like most OTA code does.

I am not aware of a ready-made library that does that. If I wanted to roll my own, I would start by studying the OTA code.